# How to set a specific amount for native token when calling CIP30 api.getUtxos() method in Nami, CCvault, Flint and other CIP30-compliant wallets?

Tags: wallet, transaction, nami, ccvault

In the [CIP30](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/) spec, we are supposed to be able to get a subset of the user's UTXOs if we specify an "amount" when calling the method `getUtxos()`:

```
api.getUtxos(amount: cbor\ = undefined, paginate: Paginate = undefined): Promise\
```

And this "amount" parameter, is supposed to allow a `Value` type which further contains `MultiAsset` types.

But calling this method like so:

```
let ScriptHash = csl.ScriptHash.from_bytes( Buffer.from(policyId, "hex") );

let Assets = csl.Assets.new();
Assets.insert(
    csl.AssetName.new( Buffer.from(assetName, "hex") ),
    csl.BigNum.from_str(amount)
);

let MultiAsset = csl.MultiAsset.new();
MultiAsset.insert(ScriptHash, Assets);

let reqdValue = csl.Value.new_from_assets(MultiAsset);
let inputUtxos = await wallet.activeApi.getUtxos(reqdValue); // CIP30 method call
```

... always gives me the following errors.

In CCVault/Eternl:

```
Error: invalid input: amount: TypeError: byteaString.startsWith is not a function
```

In Nami:

```
Inputs do not conform to this spec or are otherwise invalid.
```

In Flint:

```
An error occurred during execution of this API call.
```

What am I doing wrong here? What is the correct way of passing a `Value` parameter to `getUtxos()`?